# adding gravity to instances

Tags: physics

I an trying to create a simulation using lego bricks. i am instancing them on a cube that is hidden from rendering. i want to apply gravity and a rigid body to the bricks so the fall and land on the plane and bounce like lego bricks whaen you pour them, but when i applied a rigid body to the cube they all fall and stopped on the plane instead of all landing on the plane : [image]

how exactly would i go about making it fall all onto the plane?

EDIT: Here is the file:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: your video is flipped horizontally in case you didn't notice.

Comment: you have several problems here: 1) you basic lego isn't connected - the meshes are separated parts -> you have to connect the geometry somehow, else rigid body won't work 2) you have to apply the GN modifier because else you will have just one mesh 3) before point 2 you have to add a realize instances nodes before the output node 4) after applying the GN modifier, you have to select your mesh in edit mode and recalculate normals 5) then in edit mode separate by loose parts 6) in object mode: set origin to geometry and then...hold your breath and it might work